# Any research into "intelligence" really out of sync with iq?

Tags: intelligence, iq

Is there any research into school children who routinely perform say two standard deviations worse on iq testing, than at school or even other intelligence tests?

I'm not interested in explaining it in terms of hard work.

Comment: What research? That it happens? On their differences? What causes it? Any preliminary research/motivation that lead you to writing this question?

Comment: Yes there is.  Howard Gardner (Harvard School of Education) spent countless years researching this very topic.  Look up his Theory of Multiple Intelligence.